# Uniform License Agreement

Tags: licensing, antitrust-law

In section 3B of the [United States v Microsoft Corp Final Decision](https://www.justice.gov/atr/case-document/final-judgment-133) the court orders that "Microsoft's provision of Windows Operating System Products to Covered OEMs shall be pursuant to uniform license agreements with uniform terms and conditions." What are uniform license agreements? I have not been able to find a definition on google or Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

Uniform just means the same and license agreement means, well ... license agreement. So the decision means that every OEM has to have the same license agreement as every other OEM - Microsoft cannot make preferential deals with some OEMs and not with others.